# Listing shell variables with specific characters

Tags: shell, variables, csh

> I have in c-shell some variables referring to file names. Those
>   variables are named like:
>
> $T01aa2 $T12aa2 $T45aa2 etc.
>
> They have in common the "T" and the "aa2".
>
> How can I list these variables in a loop for instance as I would do if
>   they were filenames:
>
> I'd like to do something like:
>
> foreach ii in ($T*aa2) dosomestuff.sh $ii end
>
> Unfortunately, $T*aa2 does not apply for c-shell variable names.
>
> thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names are very different from file names.  There is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

But if you must do it, the best you can do is something with `set | grep` (or `awk` or `sed` or whatever) and maybe `eval`.  Something like this:

```
set vars=(`set | awk '$1 ~ /^T.*aa2$/ {print $1}'`)
foreach var ( $vars:q ) 
    eval 'dosomestuff "$'"$var"'"'
end
```

You may be able to get the values out of the `set` directly and skip the `eval`, but it can get tricky if the values may contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of csh but did you try escaping $ signs ? 
I mean substituting a "$" with "\$" ?